# Awaiting for message using discordJDA not working as intended

Tags: java, discord

I'm currently working on my discord bot. One problem I encountered is that I'm not able to find out how to allow the bot to wait for a user reply after a message is sent.

I also have tried reading the git documentation regarding using RestAction over here: https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/7)-Using-RestAction but it seems it does not mention anything about implementing an "await" function similar to discord.js

I tried coding to mimic such an effect:

```
public class EventHandler extends ListenerAdapter {

        private static final String PREFIX = "&";
        public static String[] args;


        public void sendMessage(String s, GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
            event
                    .getChannel()
                    .sendMessage(s)
                    .queue();
        }

        public void onGuildMessageReceived (GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {

            args = event
                    .getMessage()
                    .getContentRaw()
                    .split(" "); 

        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(PREFIX + "any_command")) {
            sendMessage("Type hello!");
            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(PREFIX + "hello") {
               sendMessage("hello there!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Main class:**

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.AccountType;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDABuilder;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JDA jda = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT)
                .setToken("token goes here")
                .setAutoReconnect(true).build();

        try {
            jda.addEventListener(new EventHandler());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

This doesn't register the hello command typed after the prompt given. My best guess would be that the condition is never met since the original condition overrides the upcoming one (args[0] is already any_command)
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the `EventWaiter` from JDA-Utilities (https://github.com/JDA-Applications/JDA-Utilities/)

Taking a quick look at the source, looks like you'll need something like this

```java
EventWaiter waiter = new EventWaiter();
// SO wouldn't let me insert new lines for some reason.
waiter.waitForEvent(GuildMessageReceivedEvent.class, (event) -> event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase("hello"), (event) -> event.getChannel().sendMessage("hello!").queue()));
```

Comment: Something else I forgot to add: you have to add the `EventWaiter` as an event listener to JDA.

`jda.addEventListener(waiter);`

Comment: yeah I realised, i implemented it onto my EventListener class after reading more about the issue. Thanks a lot though!